# Exporting Results Automatically into an Excel File In Teradata Studio Express 16.20

Tags: teradata

I want my results to open in an excel file when I run a query in Teradata Studio Express. Teradata Sql Assistant had this option, where you go and click on "export" option and whenever you run a query the resultset is always exported into an excel file. I am unable to see this option in Studio Express. Please note, my result set is populated in the Teradata Result Set Viewer, and I can export it from there but what I am looking for is to export it directly into an excel file, rather than viewing it here in teradata studio Express, when the query is run.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Editor view has an Export Results button located in the toolbar of the Editor. I tried to use it in 16.20.07 this evening to verify its behavior but encountered an internal error with a component of Studio Express. I can see that it is attempting to initiate a JDBC FastExport to route the results to the specified Excel file.

Perhaps you will have more success using this feature in Studio Express. Nevertheless, the feature is present.